# Put locations on map around user with a certain radius - android

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview, android-maps, android-location

I am working on a GPS application and was toying with the idea of putting markers around the user like in [Zombie Run](https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/net.peterd.zombierun/ss-1-320-480-160-0-be320265c313592cae43145726e87c7767fd53dc) and [SpecTrek](https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.spectrekking.light/ss-0-320-480-160-1-4be7308ade851185121fbb2e59340a77f8bdebe8) but am completely confused about how to find out the locations around the user.

I have been looking at the documentation for the Location class and have used the distanceTo() function for other things as well as MapView's latitudeSpan(), longitudeSpan() and getProjection() functions but I can't think how to decide on locations that are, for example, 100 metres around the user.

As I know the users position and I am only going to be placing markers that are ~1km away from the user, at the most, can I treat the area as flat rather than ellipsoidal and so then just could take the user's longitude and latitude and +/- from them to plot a marker around them (using some basic trigonometry such as x = cos(radius) and y = sin(radius) to keep it within the radius-sized circle around the player)?

I don't understand how long/lat correspond to actual scalar distances as in would 100long 100lat be 10 metres away from 90long 100lat? (I know these values are completely wrong but just using them to illustrate my question).

Thanks for your time,

Infinitifizz

Answer (score 2):

The distance between two longitude/latitude points is calculated with the haversine formula. Here is a link with the theoretics:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

I would use the distanceTo method which you already mentioned for your purpose. You have your current Location and all your Points of Interest. Just call Location.distanceTo(Poi) for each Point of Interest and if the distance is larger than 1000 meters you can draw the point to your map.

If you don't have your PoIs as Location objects just build them like this:

```
poiLocation = new Location(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
poiLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
poiLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
```

I used the distanceTo method in a radar like app and worked just fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but that's exactly my problem, I don't have PoIs, I want to arbitrarily put "items" on the map for users to visit as in with Zombie Run and Spec Trek.

Say the user starts the app, it shows their position in the middle of a mapview and 3 or markers around them that they have to visit, I don't know how to place those markers because I don't know how to work out say 10m from the user and then place a marker there. So I kind of need a distanceTo() type function in reverse that lets me specifiy the distance and it creates a marker at that point long/lat.

Comment: I don't think there is a method which provides you every GeoPoint or Location in a defined radius but you could calculate those points yourself. Just look into the link I provided. There is a section called "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point". There you have a formular with a given Geo Coordinate (your current location) and you provide the distance and bearing in degrees. With that formular you can calculate specific Geo Coordinates and display them on your map.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I still can't get it working though, neither in my app or on the website if I change the values. The problem with the website is that it doesn't say what value to use for the radius of the earth. So putting in the user's position (I'm in england) and having the radius of earth as the mean radius of earth taken from wikipedia as 6371, a distance of 1km and a bearing of 2 (Don't know if this should just be an int but that's what I've done) it decides a point 1km away is in Peru, which obviously isn't the case :-) Any help would be met with extreme gratitude

Comment: I tried using Math.toRadians() on all the lat1, lon1 and d/R references inside the cos, sin, asin and atan2 functions just to see if it would help but this put the marker on the same longitude but the opposite latitude so said 1km away from me in England was in the Indian Ocean near the west coast of Indonesia. :-(

Comment: Okay I've got it closer to working now, the bearing is working correctly and stuff, it's just the distance isn't. The map is plotting the 2nd marker about 10000km away rather than like 2 or 3, it is aout 10000km south of England in the Atlantic south of Ghana. Which is leading me to believe the bearing is working as the longitude is a little bit off vertical when my bearing is 2(degrees) but the distance is obviously way off.

Comment: Okay, I've got it working now, the problem is, the formulae return lat2 and lon2 in radians not degrees and so plugging the radians into a new GeoPoint() messed everything up and thought I was below Ghana.

Answer (score 1):

A little closer to the bottom of the page the formular is described a little bit better. There you can see that he converted to radians before calculating. Also it is crucial that you use the right datatypes to avoid false rounding of numbers. Here is a small code snippet which should work:

```
double lat1 = 52.104636;
double lon1 = 0.356324;

double R = 6371.0;
double d = 1.0;
double dist = d / R;
double brng = Math.toRadians(1.0);
lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);

double lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(dist) + Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(brng));
double lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(lat1),            Math.cos(dist)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
lon2 = (lon2+3*Math.PI)%(2*Math.PI) - Math.PI;

System.out.println("lat2: " + Math.toDegrees(lat2));
System.out.println("lon2: " + Math.toDegrees(lon2));
```

Comment: Ah yeah thanks Mario, I saw that below and got it pretty much working (except it was rounding because I was using floats not doubles) but I've been away for a week, I'll try and get it working by tomorrow though. Thanks so much for your help.